# how to remove menu or change TIMEOUT for selecting OS (Windows 7) in grub boot manager / bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, grub, bootloader, lenovo-laptop, timeout

when I power on my notebook (Lenovo V580c) this window appears:

[image: Image 1]

and the TIMEOUT for selecting one of them is 30 seconds.
there is only windows 7 on this laptop (in addition to default FreeDOS that initially installed on it), so I don't want see this Menu every time I turn on my notebook. or at least change the TIMEOUT to 5 seconds (for example).

I tried typing "c" for command-line grub but it seems not to detect grub commands. or maybe I couldn't find any command to do my job.
I can't even find the version of this grub!!!

So, How to find the name and the version of this bootloader?
and how to change configuration like TIMEOUT and show menu?

**UPDATE:**
this is the command-line:

[image: Image 2 - Command Line]

It's different from Linux (for example Ubuntu) Terminal.

Answer (score 8):

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and enter your password.
- You will see the following contents:

  ```
  GRUB_DEFAULT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
  GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
  GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
  ```
- You can change the default from 0 to any number, corresponding to the entry in the Grub bootup menu (first boot entry is 0, second is 1, etc.)
- You can change the "hidden timeout" (no menu); and also display the countdown (`TIMEOUT_QUIET=false`)
- You can force the grub menu to show by commenting out the two `GRUB_HIDDEN` lines with a `#` at the beginning of the line
- And set the grub menu timeout (default is 10 seconds)
- Make your changes, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit.
- **Important**: Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes you just made.
- Reboot and you should see your timeout/default entry change.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/148097/606063)

Comment: thanks but not done. I have Updated my Question according to your answer. Please look and then come back again.

Comment: On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. A part of this is including the answer in your post, [instead of simply providing a link to another page that might answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please edit your answer to include the actual solution to the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

That's GNU GRUB, version 1.xx or greater, also known as GRUB 2. With a traditional BIOS-based boot, it lives in the Master Boot Record and in the normally-unused sectors located after the MBR but before the beginning of the first partition. It also typically has its configuration file and some modules available as files within one of your disk partitions, but these parts can optionally be embedded within those disk sectors.

The instructions provided by user345866 would be applicable for configuring GRUB from within a Linux OS, but apparently you don't have one. The fact that your bootloader includes a `(No SLIC)` option makes me think your version of Windows might be a pirated one.

(`SLIC` is the older version of a BIOS-embedded Windows license, and it turned out to be duplicateable and "transplantable" to other systems. Your bootloader might be something like that. The modern version is `MSDM`: it is  tied to the specific system the license is issued for, using pretty strong cryptography.)

In that case, the GRUB bootloader might be used as a delivery mechanism for the tools used to bypass the Windows licensing check, and its configuration might be entirely embedded within those normally-unused disk sectors between the MBR and the beginning of the first partition. If so, then the GRUB configuration cannot be changed without having the tools and configuration files that were originally used to "package" that particular installation of GRUB. So unless you find a `grub.cfg` file on one of your disk partitions, you might be out of luck.